# Calling a method on a running process in python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a ***Feed*** class that uses multiprocessing to run video capture and processing. I want to stop the capturing that happens in the while loop if the `_camera_running` is false but when I call the `stop_camera_running` method it has no effect, it completes its execution but has no effect on the `_camera_running` value.

```
class Feed(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        self._camera_running = True

    def stop_camera_running(self):
        self._camera_running = False

    def run(self):
        while self._camera_running:
            # Video camture...
            # Process frame...
```

My question is, am I missing something to allow for methods to be called on a running process? I should also add that the `stop_camera_method` is controlled through an API and the feeds are stored in a list then started once they have been added. The API has access to this list of feed processes.

Answer (score 0):

Now i can't see your code where you `use stop_camera_running`

you can do the following. Assuming this is where you want to stop it

```
 def run(self):
    while self._camera_running:
        return stop_camera_running
```

the return statement in a function terminates it. Try it out.